# Interpret Json response as plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following piece of code and I need to parse the response which according to my understanding actually saves in variable 'transferFlag'

but 'transferFlag' alerts the whole ajax code while

I need the response of that ajax call which is actually returning the value of method

'getStudentIdsForTransfer' ,

how to get the response of that method?

I am new to Ajax, Jquery, Jason that is why having some trouble in understanding.

```
  var transferFlag=({
                    url: "UtilBean/getStudentIdsForTransfer",
                    handleAs: 'text',
                    data:
                    {   
                        studentId: this.studentId                       
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) { var myValue = data.myValue; },

                    failure: function() { alert("Uh oh"); }
                  });
            alert(transferFlag.toString()+ ".... Hi transfer Flag");
```

Comment: JSON *is* plain text. What you have there is a JavaScript object (**not  JSON**) - you want the JSON (which *is* plain text) *representing* that  JavaScript object-graph. (The default "toString" for plain JavaScript objects is "[object Object]", which explains the results.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/912247/2864740

Comment: Can you show the code for: UtilBean/getStudentIdsForTransfer

Comment: This method just query the database and returns a value.

Answer (score 2):

You are close to the answer..Every operations in javascript on **[JSON](http://www.json.org/)** can performed through object format. So you are getting the correct output. Do you want to convert json object in to string use

```
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

Now the data must be in the string format. Pass the data to html and iterate(**[JSTL](https://jstl.java.net)**). Jstl is the best tag lib for data manipulation in jsp pages

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript Native Function.
    **`JSON.stringify(transferFlag)`**

**Edit Part Answer:** Use the Proper Ajax call from jquery [Example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).wrote Your code in Sucess: callback Method.and then JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Got it , thank you but it alerts the whole piece of code that I wrote above while I need response of that ajax call, how to get the response?

Comment: @HappyDev Well, you have to *use* an AJAX call .. but that's a different task/question. Also, you only want to serialize ("stringify") the *data* in the AJAX payload (at the appropriate level), not all the properties used for the AJAX call. I recommend reading a tutorial.

Comment: @HappyDev you can Do same think in you success callback method.if you want to get data from success: write your code in success:.

Comment: I am using alert in success method but it doesnt show up niether in failure. is the above piece of code has some mistake?

Comment: @HappyDev Yes Goto example that i post in my answer and grab Ajax code from there.